# How do I create a Bode plot in Octave with the frequency response using Hz and not rad/s

Tags: octave

I need to create some Blode plots, and I need the frequency to be in Hertz, but Octave uses rads/s by default.

Here is my code:

```
pkg load control
s = tf('s');
S_LN= s/4000;
g = 0.4913/(0.4913 + 1.2384*S_LN + 0.9883*(S_LN^2) + S_LN^3) ;
bode(g,{1,10^4});
```

How can I plot using Hertz?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! GIven that rad is dimensionless, rad/s is technically the same as Hz. Could you please [edit] the question to clarify what the desired outcome is?

Answer (score 3):

As,

```
ω (rad/sec) = 2πf 
f (Hertz) = ω/2π
```

So you just need to divide your XData by 2π. i.e.

```matlab
XdataObjs = findobj(gcf,'-property','XData');
for k=2:3
  set(XdataObjs(k), 'XData', get(XdataObjs(k),'XData')/(2*pi));
end
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Nice. Not sure why, but I had to change the range to `for k=3:4` to correct both charts. Octave v8.3.0.

Comment: @Heath Well, not reproducible with the data in the OP on Octave v8.3.0 at my end and I got the correct output with `for k=2:3`. You might have some other objects in your figure.

Comment: good to know. I get inconsistent behaviour and even resorted to `for k=1:4` to be sure to be sure. So YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the matrix, make the operations and make the plot as you need.
The conversions are as follows

> f[Hz] = w[r/s] / 2π
> mag[dB] = 20*log10(mag[u])

1. You can get the vectors of magnitude, phase and frequency in radians per second

```matlab
[mg, ph, w] = bode (g,{1,10^4});   % Get the vectors
```

2. Make the conversions

```matlab
bfreq = w/2*pi();                  % Convert from rps to hz
mdb = 20*log10(mg);                % Conver from ratio to dB
```

3. Plot the new vectors

```matlab
subplot(2,1,1);                    % Subplot 1 of (2,1)
semilogx(bfreq, mdb);              % Plot the magnitude
zoom on;
grid on;
title('Bode');
ylabel('Magnitude[dB]');

subplot(2,1,2);                   % Subplot 2 of (2,1)
semilogx(bfreq, ph);              % Plot the phase
grid on;
zoom on;
ylabel('Phase[deg]');
xlabel('Frequency[Hz]');
```

[image: Bode plot in Hertz]